# Нужна информация по bluegiga WT-12

Tags: android, bluetooth, микроконтроллеры, monotouch, avr-gcc

Возможно кто-нибудь работал с bluetooth модулями от bluegiga WT-12.

Используя даташит, удалось за пару часов организовать блютус мышь (управляю БТ модулем с микроконтроллера Atxmega16A).

Проблема в том, что не могу найти дескриптор и последовательность данных, чтоб перевести БТ модуль в режим digitizer. Координаты касания с тачскрина снимаю, а как их через блютус загнать в андроид найти не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужен HIDDescriptorList для SDPrecord, то вам нужна спецификация от usb.org:

"HID Usage Tables"

Не помешает и эта:

"Device Class Definition for Human Interface Devices (HID)"

В первой спецификации как раз есть описание дескриптора дигитайзера на 103 странице.